# Display last comments on home page

Tags: comments, homepage

Is there a way to select and display the last X approved comments regardless of which posts or categories they belong to ?

I just want to show on my home page the last comments added on my site, but I can't find anywhere how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more complete and less abrupt answer.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'number' => '5'
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    // display any of the following indexes as you'd like
    var_dump($comment);
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) and don't pass a post id.